# Can't assign to array

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to initialize an object class.  In the object, I keep the ID of the timekeeper (person) and an array of RelatedTimekeepers. To do this, I need to append to an array with a list of RelatedID.

The function is question is AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber.  Currently, it fails a the commented line.

These are added to a object called timekeeper.

My class looks like:

```
' TIMEKEEPER CLASS
Private sTimekeeperNumber As String
Private sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers() As Variant

Public Property Let TimekeeperNumber(TimekeeperNumber As String)
    sTimekeeperNumber = TimekeeperNumber

End Property

Public Property Get TimekeeperNumber() As String
    TimekeeperNumber = sTimekeeperNumber

End Property

Public Sub AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber(RelatedTimkeeperNumber As String)
    Dim tmpArr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sRelatedTimekeeperNumbersLength As Integer
    sRelatedTimekeeperNumbersLength = ArrayCount(sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers)
    ReDim tmpArr(1 To sRelatedTimekeeperNumbersLength) As String
    For i = 1 To sRelatedTimekeeperNumbersLength

        If i = sRelatedTimekeeperNumbersLength Then
            tmpArr(i) = RelatedTimekeeperNumber
        Else
            tmpArr(i) = sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers(i)
        End If

    Next i

    ReDim Preserve sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers(1 To ArrayCount(tmpArr))

    sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers = tmpArr ' <- "Can't Reassign to array, despite ReDim'ing"

End Sub

Public Sub PrintRelatedTimekeeperNumbers()
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Long

    myArray = sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers

    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
      txt = txt & myArray(i) & vbCrLf
    Next i

    MsgBox txt

End Sub

Function ArrayCount(ByRef vArray As Variant) As Long
    lArrayCount = UBound(vArray) - LBound(vArray) + 1

End Function
```

and My procedure to build the class is:

```
Sub Init_Timekeepers()

    Dim oTimekeeper As New clsTimekeeper

    Dim sTkID As String
    oTimekeeper.TimekeeperNumber = "00089"
    oTimekeeper.AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber ("00089")
    sTkID = oTimekeeper.TimekeeperNumber

    oTimekeeper.AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber ("00091")
    oTimekeeper.AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber ("00092")

    oTimekeeper.PrintRelatedTimekeeperNumbers

End Sub
```

Before setting array, I think I am ReDim'ing, however, the compiler throws and error at the commented line.

Comment: On the Redim Preserve line add "As String"  Why do you need `preserve` anyway if you are going to write over the array?  And another thing, use Dictionaries it saves hassle with arrays.

Comment: Should I just make all my arrays variant (since my array count is variant)?

Comment: I make all my dynamic 'array-like', 'list-like' structures Dictionaries.

Comment: What's your key?

Comment: ah in those instances I write `dict.Add dict.Count, data` , so the key is the count of the dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edited** to add some hints about the rest of the code

as to the very issue of your question, just dim

```
Private sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers  As Variant
```

BTW the shown code has two typos:

```
lArrayCount = UBound(vArray) - LBound(vArray) + 1
```

should be

```
ArrayCount = UBound(vArray) - LBound(vArray) + 1
```

and:

```
Public Sub AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber(RelatedTimkeeperNumber As String)
```

should be

```
Public Sub AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber(RelatedTimekeeperNumber As String)
```

---

From your scenario description, I'd say you need the following changes (and consequent refactoring) to your code:

1. Handle `sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers` being initially empty

   then you have to change `ArrayCount` to:

   ```
   Function ArrayCount(ByRef vArray As Variant) As Long
       If IsEmpty(vArray) Then
           ArrayCount = 0
       Else
           ArrayCount = UBound(vArray) - LBound(vArray) + 1
       End If
   End Function
   ```
2. add a new element to the array

   then change `AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber(RelatedTimekeeperNumber As String)` to:

   ```
   Public Sub AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber(RelatedTimekeeperNumber As String)
       Dim sRelatedTimekeeperNumbersLength As Long

       sRelatedTimekeeperNumbersLength = ArrayCount(sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers)
       If sRelatedTimekeeperNumbersLength = 0 Then
           ReDim sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers(1 To 1) As String
       Else
           ReDim Preserve sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers(1 To sRelatedTimekeeperNumbersLength + 1) As String
       End If
       sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers(sRelatedTimekeeperNumbersLength + 1) = RelatedTimekeeperNumber
   End Sub
   ```

   and finally, change `PrintRelatedTimekeeperNumbers()` to:

   ```
   Public Sub PrintRelatedTimekeeperNumbers()
       If UBound(sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers) > 0 Then
           MsgBox Join(sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers, " ")
       Else
           MsgBox "no time keepers related to " & sTimekeeperNumber
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

---

but you make a step further by adopting other objects instead of arrays, like a `Collection` or a `Dictionary` Object

in the former case you class code would condense to:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private sTimekeeperNumber As String
    Private sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers As New Collection

    Public Property Let TimekeeperNumber(TimekeeperNumber As String)
        sTimekeeperNumber = TimekeeperNumber        
    End Property

    Public Property Get TimekeeperNumber() As String
        TimekeeperNumber = sTimekeeperNumber        
    End Property

    Public Sub AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber(RelatedTimekeeperNumber As String)            
        sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers.Add RelatedTimekeeperNumber
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrintRelatedTimekeeperNumbers()
        Dim item As Variant
        Dim txt As String
        If sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers.count > 0 Then
            For Each item In sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers
                txt = txt & item & " "
            Next
            MsgBox Trim(txt)
        Else
            MsgBox "no time keepers related to " & sTimekeeperNumber
        End If
    End Sub
```

in the latter case it'd become:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private sTimekeeperNumber As String
    Private sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Public Property Let TimekeeperNumber(TimekeeperNumber As String)
        sTimekeeperNumber = TimekeeperNumber

    End Property

    Public Property Get TimekeeperNumber() As String
        TimekeeperNumber = sTimekeeperNumber

    End Property

    Public Sub AddRelatedTimekeeperNumber(RelatedTimekeeperNumber As String)
        sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers.Add RelatedTimekeeperNumber, ""
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrintRelatedTimekeeperNumbers()
        Dim item As Variant
        Dim txt As String
        If sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers.count > 0 Then
            MsgBox Join(sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers.Keys, " ")
        Else
            MsgBox "no time keepers related to " & sTimekeeperNumber
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a Subscript out of range in ArrayCount() now.

Comment: see edit to handle some flaws in your code. if my answer solved your _original_ question you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you

Comment: Shoud it not be Private sRelatedTimekeeperNumbers()  As Variant with a ()?

Comment: as you already experienced, it should not. since that way you are declaring an array of `Variant`s instead of a `Variant` variable  (that will eventually hold an array)

Comment: Ok, so if I do that, I get a "type mismatch" which I'm assuming "tmpArr As String" needs to be "tmpArr As Variant" as well

Comment: and it solved the _original_ question which is _"Can't assign to array"_. new issues call for new posts

Comment: you seem not to appreciate my solving your issue (and correcting some other code flaws, too) nor understand this site rules.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: Thanks adding a clear critique and going above an beyond.  I'm new to VB, so really helps.